# SQL Server 2012 Express connection to MS Access 2010

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I'm a newby with SQL. I am trying to connect sql server 2012 express (local) to a project on ms acces 2010 using the wizard but it is giving me this error.

Connection failed:
SQL State:'01000'
SWL Server Error: 2
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionOpen(connect()).
Connection failed:
SQL State:'08001'
SQL Server Error:17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

I'm wondering if somebody can give me a hand on these please. Many thanks in advance.

OS: windows 7 (32 bit)

Jhun

Comment: ....Additional info: I have installed ODBC driver already. And I have configured and added MS ODBC Driver for SQL into the ODBC SQL Server setup. And still FAILED when trying to connect on the Test Data Source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, SQL Server Express installs itself as a SQL Server *instance* named `SQLEXPRESS`. In those cases when specifying the SQL Server for the ODBC DSN you need to use `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`, not just `(local)`.

Example: After selecting `External Data` > `ODBC Database` from the Access ribbon you choose "New" on the Select Data Source dialog

[image: SelectDataSource.png]

After selecting the SQL Server driver if you use the drop-down list and simply select `(local)`...

[image: local.png]

...then the connection will fail. However, if you manually add the `\SQLEXPRESS` *instance name* then the connection should succeed

[image: sqlexpress.png]

Comment: Thanks so much Gord, very kind of you. Your solution actually worked but on the ms access side now when attempting to connect it is giving me this new problem now " Connection failed: SQLState: '08001' SQLServerError:53 SQLState: 'HYT00' SQL Server Error: 0." Thanks once again.

Comment: Got it sorted Gord. Thanks so much for your help. Appreciate it much.